# NHibernate Doesn't Log Errors

Tags: nhibernate, log4net

I'm getting an NHibernate exception that I want to try to get more info on, but it doesn't seem to be logging errors.  I was actually looking to get more granular error info, but discovered the initial problem of not logging errors at all.
Here's my log4net sectionf rom config file:

```
<log4net>
<appender name="NHibernateAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value=".\\Logs\\NHibernate.log" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <maximumFileSize value="10000KB" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <header value="[Header]&#xD;&#xA;" />
    <footer value="[Footer]&#xD;&#xA;" />
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="NHibernateSQLAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value=".\\Logs\\NHibernate.Sql.log" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <maximumFileSize value="10000KB" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <header value="[Header]&#xD;&#xA;" />
    <footer value="[Footer]&#xD;&#xA;" />
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<logger name="NHibernate" additivity="false">
  <level value="ERROR" />
  <appender-ref ref="NHibernateAppender" />
</logger>
<logger name="NHibernate.SQL" additivity="false">
  <level value="ERROR" />
  <appender-ref ref="NHibernateSQLAppender" />
</logger>
</log4net>
```

I've tried "ALL" as well; it writes "DEBUG" and "INFO", but no "ERROR" entries.  Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you add this into your web.config:

```
<appSettings>
   ...
   <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

And:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true">
        <listeners>
            <add name="textWriterTraceListener" 
                type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" 
                initializeData="log.txt" />
        </listeners>
    </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

This will show up any problems log4net may be having itself, e.g. trying to configure your appenders.

Comment: Rats!  Looks like everything configured ok - at least for that appender (tho ur tip did uncover an issue w/ another appender).

Comment: Also checked 2 c if I was doing anything fluently/in code w/ NH that would conflict w/ my config file settings, but didn't find anything...